# Get relation for multiple objects with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

A `User` has many `Phone`s. I want to get all the phones from `active` users. I can do:

```
$phones = [];
$users = User::with('phones')->where('active', 1)->get();
foreach($users as $user) {
    $phones = array_merge($phones, $user->phones->toArray());
}
dd($phones); // <- Here are all the phones.
```

But I'm not sure it's the more elegant or laravel-ish way. Is there a built in magic function for such a case? Can I get all the phones from active users without writing a loop and insert in an Array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method:

```
$phones = Phone::whereHas('user', function($q) {
    $q->where('active', 1);
})->get();
```

Comment: You are too fast. :p

Comment: You need to call get();

Comment: Thanks! (I can accept your answer in a few minutes)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`whereExists`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-exists-clauses), which can be more efficient if you're not using data from the users table:

```
Phone::whereExists(function($query) {
    $query->select(\DB::raw('NULL'))
          ->from('users')
          ->whereRaw('users.id = phones.user_id AND users.active = 1')
})->get();
```